# Python or Powershell - Import Folder Name & Text file Content in Folder into Excel

Tags: python, excel, powershell

I have been looking at some python modules and powershell capabilities to try and import some data a database recently kicked out in the form of folders and text files.

File Structure:

Top Level Folder > FOLDER (Device hostname) > Text File (also contains the hostname of device) (with data I need in a single cell in Excel)

The end result I am trying to accomplish is have the first cell be the FOLDER (device name) and the second column contain the text of the text file within that folder.

I found some python modules but they all focus on pulling directly from a text doc...I want to have the script or powershell function iterate through each folder and pull both the folder name and text out.

Comment: No this is a place where people give direction on maybe a module I am missing or a function in powershell...hey check out this feature. BAM collaberation. No one is asking for code...simply an idea if there is a method to accomplish this.

Comment: I usually don't mind questions like this, but yours is _way_ too broad. You want help with databases, excel, _and_ file IO? Plus, we have no idea how experienced of a programmer you are, so even someone bothers to compose an answer, it might be completely lost on you? Do your homework and come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: You could also use VBA or even the command shell.  With PS, you could simply use the `Dir` command to generate your list of files, then import them into Excel using VBA.  Post back with your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely do-able in Powershell. If I understand your question correctly, you're going to want to use `Get Child-Item`and `Get Content` then `-recurse` if necessary. As far as an export you're going to want to use `Out-File` which can be a hassle when exporting directly to xlsx. If you had some code to work with I could help better but until then this should get you started in the right direction. I would read up on the `Get`commands because Powershell is very simple to write but powerful.

Comment: Actually, dumping data into Excel isn't too bad. You can pipe an array of objects to `convertto-csv -del "`t" -notype` and pipe that to `clip`, then in your Excel comobject you use the `PasteSpecial()` method on a cell. It's pretty clean and easy all-in-all

Answer (score 0):

Well,  Since you're asking in a general sense -- you can do this project simply in either choice of script languages.  If it were me -- and I had to do this job once -- I'd probably just bang out a PoSH script to do it.  If this script had to be run repeatedly, and potentially end up with more complex functions I'd probably then switch to Python (but that's just based on my personal preference as PoSH is pretty powerful in a Windows env).  Really this seems like a 15 line recursive function in either choice.

You can look up "recursive function in powershell" and the same for python and get plenty of code examples, as File Tree Walks (FTW :) ) are one of the most solved problems on sites like this. You'd just replace whatever the other person is doing in their walk with a read of the file and write.  You probably also want to output in CSV format because it's easier and imports into excell just fine.